# What does this 27017 stands for in the following code?

Tags: node.js

```
var employeeProvider = new EmployeeProvider('localhost', 27017);
```

What is this 27017?

This code is written in Node.js.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's most likely a port number. In this case, it's probably specifying the connection info for a MongoDB server (since 27017 is the default port that Mongo uses).

Answer (score 1):

In itself, the code is just invoking the EmployeeProvider function with two arguments.. One string 'localhost', and one number 27017. The code can't mean anything else if you don't know what is the code behind that function. That said, it looks like the function opens a MongoDB connection on the default port (27017) to the mongodb server on the local machine.